# "Advanced" SQL Query on Wordpress DB

Tags: sql, wordpress, nested

I'm trying to perform a query on my WordPress DB where I sum up the value of a custom field called "total", IF the field "payment_settled" equals 1. Additionally I'd like to group the result per month. Now, you'll see my half-assed attempt below, I understand why this doesn't work, but have no idea how to actually make it work...can only assume I need to do some nested select statements of sort or some other wizardry, but who knows. Either way I would be eternally grateful to whoever that can that can help...

```
SELECT SUM(meta_value) AS total, meta_key
FROM wp_postmeta AS PM
INNER JOIN wp_posts
ON PM.post_id = wp_posts.id
WHERE (PM.meta_key = 'total') 
AND (PM.meta_key = 'payment_settled' AND PM.meta_value = '1')
GROUP BY MONTH(wp_posts.post_date)
```

Cheers,

Mikael

Comment: You are asking for rows where PM.meta_key = 'total' AND (AT THE SAME TIME) PM.meta_key = 'total'... I'd say try OR instead of AND and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do but I reckon the following should help....

```
SELECT  SUM(x.total) AS grandtotal FROM (
SELECT ID, total.meta_value AS total, payment_settled.meta_value AS payment_settled FROM
wp_posts 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='payment_settled') payment_settled
ON wp_posts.id=payment_settled.post_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT post_id, meta_value, meta_key FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='total') total
ON wp_posts.id=total.post_id
) x WHERE x.total IS NOT NULL AND x.payment_settled='1'
```

If you want it grouped by the POST ID then

```
SELECT x.ID, SUM(x.total) AS grandtotal FROM (
SELECT ID, total.meta_value AS total, payment_settled.meta_value AS payment_settled FROM
wp_posts 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='payment_settled') payment_settled
ON wp_posts.id=payment_settled.post_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT post_id, meta_value, meta_key FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='total') total
ON wp_posts.id=total.post_id
) x WHERE x.total IS NOT NULL AND x.payment_settled='1'
GROUP BY x.ID
```

If my assumptions of your data is correct, then it should be fairly easy to group by date too.

```
SELECT  SUM(x.total),CONCAT( YEAR(x.post_date), '-', MONTH(x.post_date) ) AS grandtotal 
FROM (
SELECT ID, total.meta_value AS total, payment_settled.meta_value AS payment_settled, wp_posts.post_date 
FROM wp_posts 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='payment_settled') payment_settled
ON wp_posts.id=payment_settled.post_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT post_id, meta_value, meta_key FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='total') total
ON wp_posts.id=total.post_id
) x 
WHERE x.total IS NOT NULL AND x.payment_settled='1' GROUP BY CONCAT( YEAR(x.post_date), '-', MONTH(x.post_date) 
)
```

Comment: Note that grouping by GROUP BY MONTH(wp_posts.post_date) will group by month in every year. Eg, it will group September 2014 with September 2013 and 2012 etc. You will probably want to add the year too

Comment: Nick, I have NO idea what's going on in your query but it WORKS! Any chance you could provide a bit of commentary, get cocked eyed just looking at it...but would love to understand it.

Comment: 1) The main table is the wp_posts table
Extra fields will go to wp_postmeta table.
Extra fields for payment_settled are:
SELECT * FROM  wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='payment_settled'

Extra fields for total are:
SELECT * FROM  wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='total'

Comment: 2) Crosstab the wp_postmeta values.
We do this by selecting the wp_post data and then left outer joining the data in the wp_postmeta tables.

SELECT ID, total.meta_value AS total, payment_settled.meta_value AS payment_settled, wp_posts.post_date 
FROM wp_posts 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='payment_settled') payment_settled
ON wp_posts.id=payment_settled.post_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT post_id, meta_value, meta_key FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='total') total
ON wp_posts.id=total.post_id
This effectively becomes our table which we call x

Comment: 3) Lastly we need to sum the totals, only when payment_settled = '1', and group by the post_data

Comment: SELECT SUM(x.total),CONCAT( YEAR(x.post_date),'-',MONTH(x.post_date) ) AS grandtotal
FROM (
SELECT ID, total.meta_value AS total, payment_settled.meta_value AS payment_settled, wp_posts.post_date 
FROM wp_posts 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='payment_settled') payment_settled
ON wp_posts.id=payment_settled.post_id
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT post_id, meta_value, meta_key FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='total') total
ON wp_posts.id=total.post_id
) x 
WHERE x.total IS NOT NULL AND x.payment_settled='1' GROUP BY CONCAT( YEAR(x.post_date), '-', MONTH(x.post_date) 
)

Comment: Thank you Nick, you're an absolute star! I'll be doing a lot more of these type of queries in the future so understanding how to compose my own is key!